# Pandas - Remove duplicates across multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to efficiently remove duplicates in Pandas in which duplicates are inverted across two columns. For example, in this data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
key = pd.DataFrame({'p1':['a','b','a','a','b','d','c'],'p2':['b','a','c','d','c','a','b'],'value':[1,1,2,3,5,3,5]})
df = pd.DataFrame(key,columns=['p1','p2','value'])
print frame

       p1 p2 value
    0  a  b    1
    1  b  a    1
    2  a  c    2
    3  a  d    3
    4  b  c    5
    5  d  a    3
    6  c  b    5
```

I would want to remove rows 1, 5 and 6, leaving me with just:

```
      p1 p2 value
    0  a  b    1
    2  a  c    2
    3  a  d    3
    4  b  c    5
```

Thanks in advance for ideas on how to do this.

Answer (score 14):

Reorder the p1 and p2 values so they appear in a canonical order:

```
mask = df['p1'] < df['p2']
df['first'] = df['p1'].where(mask, df['p2'])
df['second'] = df['p2'].where(mask, df['p1'])
```

yields

```
In [149]: df
Out[149]: 
  p1 p2  value first second
0  a  b      1     a      b
1  b  a      1     a      b
2  a  c      2     a      c
3  a  d      3     a      d
4  b  c      5     b      c
5  d  a      3     a      d
6  c  b      5     b      c
```

Then you can drop_duplicates:

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['value', 'first', 'second'])
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
key = pd.DataFrame({'p1':['a','b','a','a','b','d','c'],'p2':['b','a','c','d','c','a','b'],'value':[1,1,2,3,5,3,5]})
df = pd.DataFrame(key,columns=['p1','p2','value'])

mask = df['p1'] < df['p2']
df['first'] = df['p1'].where(mask, df['p2'])
df['second'] = df['p2'].where(mask, df['p1'])
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['value', 'first', 'second'])
df = df[['p1', 'p2', 'value']]
```

yields

```
In [151]: df
Out[151]: 
  p1 p2  value
0  a  b      1
2  a  c      2
3  a  d      3
4  b  c      5
```