# python: keep only unique combinations from two columns in either order of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have a problem very similar to the question here: [Unique combination of two columns with mixed values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68531779/unique-combination-of-two-columns-with-mixed-values)

however my original dataframe has an additional column of values. This value is always the same for each combination (ie A,B,5 and B,A,5). My plan is to essentially  ignore it when creating the key column and then drop duplicate keys.

My ideal solution would be a modified version of the `df['key'] = np.sort(df.to_numpy(), axis=1).sum(1)` solution that accounts for the third column since as is I get the error `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'`

I also tried `network['key'] = np.sort(network['col1', 'col2'].to_numpy(), axis=1).sum(1)` but I get `KeyError: ('col1', 'col2')`

I have also tried modifying the solution here: [Python: Pandas: two columns with same values, alphabetically sorted and stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40187874/python-pandas-two-columns-with-same-values-alphabetically-sorted-and-stored)
to be  `df['key'] = np.minimum(df['col1'], df['col2']) + np.maximum(df['col1'], df['col2'])` but I get a very long message starting with  `A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead`

I have also tried the following solutions with no luck:

[(pandas) Drop duplicates based on subset where order doesn't matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44792969/pandas-drop-duplicates-based-on-subset-where-order-doesnt-matter)

[Pandas complicated duplicate removal with three comparisons to other rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73229047/pandas-complicated-duplicate-removal-with-three-comparisons-to-other-rows)

[(pandas) Drop duplicates based on subset where order doesn't matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44792969/pandas-drop-duplicates-based-on-subset-where-order-doesnt-matter?noredirect=1&lq=1)

example input:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 5 |
| B | A | 5 |

desired output:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 5 |

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there sample input data and expected output?

Comment: look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30689236/pandas-remove-duplicates-across-multiple-columns

Answer (score 0):

With the following toy dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "p1": ["a", "b", "a", "a", "b", "d", "c"],
        "p2": ["b", "a", "c", "d", "c", "a", "b"],
        "value": [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 3, 5],
    },
    columns=["p1", "p2", "value"],
)

print(df)
# Output
  p1 p2  value
0  a  b      1
1  b  a      1
2  a  c      2
3  a  d      3
4  b  c      5
5  d  a      3
6  c  b      5
```

Here is one way to do it:

```py
df = df.loc[
    (df["p1"] + df["p2"]).apply(sorted).drop_duplicates(keep="first").index, :
].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Then:

```py
  p1 p2  value
0  a  b      1
1  a  c      2
2  a  d      3
3  b  c      5
```